# Hashing a password before form submission on Server

Tags: java, javascript, android, hash, sha512

Below function use in JavaScript(**forms.js** include) for hashing a password.
Whats is the equivalent in JAVA,

```
function formhash(form, password) {
      console.log("Hashing form");
      // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field.
      var p = document.createElement("input");
      // Add the new element to our form.
      form.appendChild(p);
      p.name = "p";
      p.type = "hidden"
      p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
      // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
      password.value = "";
      // Finally submit the form.
      form.submit();
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: You should use ssl instead.

Comment: @jeroen Server side is decoding the password on there end, so i cant change encryption technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code that does it. Copied from http://runnable.com/U8lo-rXJWGlhL-OG/sha512-for-java

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class SHA512 {
      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          String password = "pass@word1";

            if ((args.length == 1) && (args[0].length() > 0))
            {
                password = args[0];
            }
            System.out.println("Password: " + password + " in SHA512 is:");
            System.out.println(hashText(password));
      }

    public static String convertByteToHex(byte data[])
    {
        StringBuffer hexData = new StringBuffer();
        for (int byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < data.length; byteIndex++)
            hexData.append(Integer.toString((data[byteIndex] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));

        return hexData.toString();
    }

    public static String hashText(String textToHash) throws Exception
    {
        final MessageDigest sha512 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        sha512.update(textToHash.getBytes());

        return convertByteToHex(sha512.digest());
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

If using a different character set, pass it to `getBytes`. Example `textToHash.getBytes("UTF-8")`

Comment: This may not work with complex passwords because the encoding is not set when calling `textToHash.getBytes()`. Therefore on different platforms (Windows, Linux, ..) the result will be different.

Comment: @Robert can you please give best solution which works for on all plateform

Comment: `textToHash.getBytes("UTF-8")` by calling this line , it will works for all plateform.

Comment: I don't have any experience in JavaScript and encoding. I have read that JavaScript uses UTF-16 as encoding internally, but I am not sure if this applies to your pasword hashing code, too.